# Easy Color Detection in python 2.7

Tags: python, colors, detection

**Hi**,

i am working on a project at the time and i am trying to see if a speciffic area on screen matches a speciffic color of my choice. i've tried a couple of things but none of them seemed to be working. is there any easy way to do this in python 2.7?

Comment: can you show what you have tried(even it does not work)? at least we will understand what are you using/witch packages. OS?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us what you have tried so far and how it failed. Note that _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "_

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what module you are working with. I.e; Turtle Graphics, Tkinter, etc.

Comment: This does not appear to be a useful answer since it only hints that a solution _might_ be available, without actually saying what that solution might be.